# Why am I suddenly being notified of privileges?

Tags: support, bug, user-interface, review, privileges

Yesterday, I got a notification informing me that I had received access to the Edit review queue. Today, I was notified that I had received access to the Reopen votes review queue.

Not to brag, but I've had over 20k rep for a long time, so I'm not sure why I'm being notified of privileges I've had for a long time. Can anyone clarify on why this is occurring?

Comment: I've gotten this on other stack exchanges.

Answer (score 6):

See here: [New onboarding for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363485/new-onboarding-for-review-queues)

From the question:

> We are also showing a popover to users who earned access to review queues in the past, but have never done a review or haven't reviewed in the last 30 days. This popover is only appearing for the next 90 days. The goal is to engage users who may not have interacted with the queues since we made visual design changes and improved communication about suspensions.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363510/674198) highlights your issue:

> The posting states,
>
> > We are also showing a popover to users who earned access to review queues in the past, **but have never done a review or haven't reviewed in the last 30 days**.
>
> I am seeing the popover for queues where I have reviewed ***within the past two days on the very same site*** (specifically Stack Overflow).

At 13:41 on 4/22/21 [status-planned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned) was added to the header of the answer by SE staff member [kristinalustig♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/344828/kristinalustig).